# VB.Net - Dataset function keeps giving an error

Tags: .net, vb.net, dataset

My dataset keeps getting to the

```
Catch ex As Exception.
```

And I don't know what the problem is.
Can someone help me?

```
Public Function Tifcheck(zoektif As String) As Boolean
        Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd3 As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\klaasjelle\Documents\Database3.accdb"
        con2.Open()
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * From Data Where Tif = '" + zoektif + 
"'"
        cmd3 = New OleDbDataAdapter(Tifcheck, zoektif)
        cmd3.Fill(ds)
        MsgBox(ds.Tables(2).Rows.Count)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("fout")
    End Try

    con2.Close()
    Return Tifcheck
End Function
```

I hope you will get what, are you seeing an error.
Or is it just my code.
Please tell me.

Comment: Either remove the `Try` statement or change `MsgBox("fout")` to `MsgBox(ex.Message)` and then tell us what the actual error is.

Comment: How about you give us the information from the exception?  You should be calling `ToString` on the exception to get all the available information.

Comment: When I change `msgbox("fout")` to `msgbox(ex.message)` it says _Layout of the initialization string does not meet specification starting at index 0._

Comment: Two things look odd: a) when you create cmd3, you pass Tifcheck as the first argument, but Tifcheck is the name of the method. That doesn't look right. b) It's been a few years since I've done any VB so I might be wrong, but you need to set Tifcheck to a value (Tifcheck = true) to set the return value, You have Return Tifchack but have not set it anywhere.

Comment: @Klaas-JelleRas now you got the error message, yay! Try searching for this on google or right now, you'll get a few different ways for trying to fix that problem. Also, don't concatenate your sql !

Comment: why call the name of the function recursively in: `OleDbDataAdapter(Tifcheck, zoektif)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing adding your connection to your command.

```
cmd2.Connection = con2
```

Added the line above to your code.

```
Public Function Tifcheck(zoektif As String) As Boolean
        Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con2 As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd3 As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\klaasjelle\Documents\Database3.accdb"
        con2.Open()
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * From Data Where Tif = '" + zoektif +    "'"
        cmd2.Connection = con2
        cmd3 = New OleDbDataAdapter(Tifcheck, zoektif)
        cmd3.Fill(ds)
        MsgBox(ds.Tables(2).Rows.Count)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("fout")
    End Try

    con2.Close()
    Return Tifcheck
End Function
```